# JQuery div clicks through div and calls both functions

Tags: jquery, css

I have two problems with my jquery code.
The first problem is when I click the redbox it will zoom out and switch position, and when I click it again it switches position again and I don't know how to fix that.

Second problem is when I click the black `close` box it clicks through the div and clicks the `open` (redbox) also.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/106/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/109/

You need stopPropagation in your close click handler. If you don't have this stop then the click will bubble to the div itself which runs that click handler code for a_demo_threee, so the position gets changed.

You need to reset your top and left, because the div click handler always does -80px for top from the current top position, which is why it always repositions and more and more to the top left. Now that we reset it so it won't go offscreen.

```
$(".a_demo_threee").click(function (e) { //opens the login

    e.stopPropagation();
    if( !$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "top": "-=80px",
            "left": "-=300px",
        }, 1000).addClass('open');
    }    

    $("#contentlogin").show(); 
});

    $("#close").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".a_demo_threee").stop().animate({
            "width": "250px",
            "height": "150px",
            "top":"80px",
            "left":"300px"
        }, 1000).removeClass('open');

        $("#contentlogin").hide();
    });
```

Comment: thanks that fix one of the problems.
the other one is still there when you click the zoomed out red box

Answer (score 0):

Move `#close` out of `.a_demo_threee`.

Try:

HTML:

```
<a class="a_demo_threee">
    <div id="contentlogin"></div>     
    <div id="login"></div>
</a>
<div id="close">CLOSE</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#contentlogin").hide();
$(".a_demo_threee").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
    $(".a_demo_threee").stop().animate({
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "top": "-=80px",
        "left": "-=300px",
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#close").fadeIn();
    },800);
    $("#contentlogin").show(); 
});
$("#close").click(function () {        
    $(".a_demo_threee").stop().animate({
        "width": "250px",
        "height": "150px",
        "top":"80px", //reset position
        "left":"300px"
    }, 1000);
    $("#close").fadeOut();
    $("#contentlogin").hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/108/)